# jsp hashset and select tag

Tags: java, jsp

I have java HashSet:

```
private Set<UserRole> rolesList = new HashSet<UserRole>();
```

And I have select tag in jsp:

```
<select id="roles" name="roles" path="roles">
       <option value="NONE">Select</option>
       <c:forEach items="${rolesList}" var="role">
         <option value="${role.role_id}">${role.role}</option>
       </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Now I want to do next: I want to iterate over roles List multiple times(while user wnats to add more roles), create new HashSet and return it as new attribute. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found deeply in Google that this class can be used to map multiple select items to backend collection: **CustomCollectionEditor**.